# Get amount of records from one table using join

Tags: mysql

This is the situation:

- I've got 3 tables, **user**, **group**, **user_group (relational table)**
- In *user* we have: **id**
- In *group* we have: **id, people (number of maximum people that can be in the group)**
- In *user_group*: **group_id, user_id**

What I want to accomplish in the same query, is to get all the *groups* that are not full yet. Which means there are less *user_group (in total)* associated to the group than *people (group.people)* there are in the *group*.

Eg: the group with id=5 with people=6 and there are 6 user_group with group_id=5. So the query I want to get to, wouldn't get group.id=5

This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT `group`.*
FROM `group`
JOIN `user_group` ON `user_group`.`group_id` = `group`.`id`
WHERE `group`.`people` > ¿COUNT(total_user_gruop)?
```

I thought about to make a subquery to get the total amount of user_groups per group, but I have no idea how to achieve that or if it's even possible...

Thanks people!

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause.

`HAVING` executes after the GROUP BY and counts thus you have the count you need to compare against the group people.

I use a distinct here only because I don't know if you allow duplicates in the user group table; and I assume such a duplicate if existed shouldn't count more than once against the total.

```
SELECT G.Group_ID, count(Distinct UG.User_ID)
FROM user_group UG
INNER JOIN `group` G
 on UG.Group_ID = G.ID
GROUP BY G.Group_ID
HAVING count(Distinct UG.User_ID) < G.People
```

Comment: I do not allow duplicates. But I've learnt something new with your query. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this query.

```
Select `group`.*, count(`user_group`.user_id) as current_users from `user_group` 
inner join `group` on `group`.id = `user_group`.group_id
group by `user_group`.group_id
having count(`user_group`.user_id) < `group`.people
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solve your problems.

```
SELECT *
FROM `group`
INNER JOIN `user_group` ON `group`.`id` = `user_group`.`group_id`
GROUP BY `user_group`.`group_id`
HAVING COUNT(`user_group`.`user_id`) < `group`.`people`
```